# how to do hover span property with angular 2

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to do span hover like this `Major` span in the image below when we hover out it just look like `story` span . need some css implementation. to make a boarder around it as well as the edit icon as shown in fig

## Need to implement

[image]

I tried so far

```css
span:hover {
    border : 2px solid;
    border-color : darkgrey;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<span> Active</span>
```

Comment: Which part of the image are you talking about?

Comment: `Major` when we hover i look like this as shown in image

Comment: otherwise it look like `story`

Comment: Add that vital information to your question so that people don't have to guess.

Comment: you'll need to use javascript to display something like you want.

Comment: I am using angular 2

Comment: @Reddy of course it's possible with CSS. Why would you need javascript?

Comment: see if this is what you want. You can't "click" the edit, but you get the tooltip - https://jsfiddle.net/5ov9j05x/2/

Comment: @RobScott no, must  boarder around span with editable icon

Comment: I suggest you edit your post with more information then, such as what exactly you need and the HTML as well (not just the styling). It's the reason why they've downvoted you as well

Comment: I already update the question

Comment: @Turnip you are right, and I did post a answer with HTML and CSS solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample code is below. You can get the basic idea from this.

I have used fontAwesome icons for demo purpose.

```css
div{
  padding:5px 0px 5px 5px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.fa.fa-pencil{
  background-color:grey;
  display:none;
  padding:4px;
}

.fa.fa-angle-double-up{
  display:none;
}

div:hover .fa.fa-pencil{
  display:initial;
}

div:hover .fa.fa-angle-double-up{
  display:initial;
}

div:hover .fa.fa-bookmark{
  display:none;
}

div:hover{
  border : 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div>
 <i class="fa fa-bookmark"></i>
 <i class="fa fa-angle-double-up"></i>
  <span> Major </span>
  <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: @MalikKashmiri glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

I used Some random Images to show you.. Please check this snippet and let me know..

```css
span:hover {
    border : 2px solid;
    border-color : darkgrey;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align:top;
}
span img:first-child {
  display: none;  
}
span img:last-child {
  display: none;  
}
span:hover img:last-child {
  display: inline-block;
  width:14px;
   border : 2px solid;
    border-color : red;
  background:gray;
  
}
span:hover img:first-child {
  display: inline-block;  
   width:16px;
}
```

```html
<span> <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/imoticons/105/imoticon_15-128.png" /> 
   
Active<img id="edit" title="click to edit" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/imoticons/105/imoticon_12-128.png" /></span>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
span:hover{
    border : 2px solid;
    border-color : darkgrey;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<span> Active</span>
```